# kubectl create deployment command using template example

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

The [kubernetes doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/#creating-a-service-for-an-application-running-in-five-pods) has a deprecated `kubectl run` command that I'm looking forward to run using `kubectl create deployment` command with `--template` option without using external json/yaml file. I'd appreciate your help in this.

The deprecated command that I'm looking  forward to translate is below:
`kubectl run hello-world --replicas=5 --labels="run=load-balancer-example" --image=gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0  --port=8080`

Simply put, how do i re-write the above `kubectl run` command with `kubectl create deployment` command using `--template` option?

Comment: can you please elaborate your question..

Comment: What you want is not clear from your desc. So ask exactly what you want, what you did so far, what your output/error/problem now, etc.

Comment: @RajeshDeshpande update the question on the final line. I hope the title of the question reflects this as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `run-pod/v1` generator in `kubectl run` command as it is not deprecated for Pod resource instead of `deployment/apps.v1` for deployments, find more information about Kubernetes API generators [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/conventions/#generators).

```
kubectl run hello-world --replicas=5 --labels="run=load-balancer-example" --image=gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0  --port=8080 --generator=run-pod/v1
```